# Skimage filters.sobel_v result not making sense. Why?

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, scikit-image, sobel

In [scikit-image's documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.sobel_v) it says that the kernel for detecting the vertical lines, is:

```
1   0  -1
2   0  -2
1   0  -1
```

If I do:

```
img = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
Lx = filters.sobel_v(img)
```

and, then print `Lx`, I get:

```
Lx
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 
0.0000 2.0000 0.0000 
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
```

Which doesn't make any sense, since the result should be:

```
1*(-1) + 3*1 + 4*(-2) + 6*2 + 7*(-1) + 9*1 = -16 + 24 = 8
```

and not `2`, at the central position.

What is going on?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very useful.

Comment: And thanks for fixing my convolution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is due to a **scaling factor** `1/4`.

The Sobel kernel for vertical edge detection is usually defined as:

[image: Gv]

This kernel can be decomposed as the product of a smoothing kernel and a derivative kernel like this:

[image: outer product]

In order for the smoothing kernel to be a true averaging filter, it should be scaled by a factor `1/(1+2+1) = 1/4`. By doing so, the Sobel kernel becomes:

[image: Gv scaled]

Although the scaling factor is not mentioned in the documentation, it is actually used in the implementation (check out the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/filters/edges.py#L21) to convince yourself).